# buttons action runtime in windev

Tags: button, runtime, action, windev

i'm creating a x number of buttons runtime in this way:

```
btn is Control   
btn <- ControlCreate(name,typButton,mouseX,mouseY,mouseXRel-mouseX,mouseYRel-mouseY,True)
btn..Caption = name
btn..Process[trtClick] = buttonAction
```

the `buttonAction` code is:

```
Info("You pressed: " + btn..Caption)
```

But the result of the buttonAction is always the last button name I create, for eg. I create a button named "Luca" and when I click it the result is: *You pressed: Luca*. Then i create a new button named "Antonio" but when I press "Luca" button the output is *You pressed Antonio*. How can I assign one button action runtime for every button?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create a control per button ?
Where did you run the creation of the buttons ?
Like:

```
btn1 is Control   
btn1 <- ControlCreate("test1",typButton,mouseX,mouseY,mouseXRel-mouseX,mouseYRel-mouseY,True)
btn1..Caption = "test1"
btn1..Process[trtClick] = buttonAction

btn2 is Control   
btn2 <- ControlCreate("test2",typButton,mouseX,mouseY,mouseXRel-mouseX,mouseYRel-mouseY,True)
btn2..Caption = "test2"
btn2..Process[trtClick] = buttonAction
```

What result do you get ?
I don't have the last version of Windev for tests.

I'm afraid "btn" became shared to the windows when you use

```
<- ControlCreate
```